# How do I add specifically found (OCR) text into a list and write it to an excel file? [pytesseract]

Tags: python, machine-learning, ocr

I want to extract certain information from many PNG/JPEG files through pytesseract and write them into an excel file if possible.

I've figured out how to extract the text from the pictures but what I haven't figured out is:

1) How do I extract specific information instead of a whole blob of words? For example, I want the account numbers and reference numbers from each photo, nothing else.

2) How do I write these account numbers and reference numbers into an external file such as excel?

I'll attach what I've got so far below:

I've heard that using pandas dataframes was a good way to append data into columns for Excel but I'm not sure if I can do that for a task like this.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import pandas as pd

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

im = Image.open("C:/Users/user1/desktop/scripts/ocr/example bills/pic.jpg")


content = pd.DataFrame()
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang= 'eng')
temp = pd.DataFrame({'Words':[text]})
content.append(temp)

content.head()

print(text)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('wordstest.xlsx')
content.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Expected Results:

An excel file with two columns, account number and reference number.

Actual Results:

An excel file with no data.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a dataframe to a spreadsheet try this

```
content.to_csv('wordstest.csv',sep=',')
```

This can be opened in excel. If you need more columns just add them to the dataframe and then write the csv file

Comment: If this does not work then there is something wrong with your DataFrame. Try
temp.to_csv('wordstest.csv',sep=',') and see if that wokrs

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter the text that you have read from the image or find the portions of the image that you want to read before actually reading them with tesseract. For filtering the read text you can use regexes and for finding the portions in the image you'll have to use some of the computer vision algorithms that predict some portions of the image (object detection) and train them on your data.

And for adding the dataframe to excel just use pandas `to_csv` or `to_excel` methods